# How can I add one more join to the query which has GROUP BY and HAVING clauses?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN tags_pivot tp 
     ON p.id = tp.post_id
INNER JOIN tags t
     ON t.id = tp.tag_id AND t.name IN ('mysql', 'php')
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

It selects all posts which are tagged with both `[mysql]` and `[php]` tags. I have one more existence named `"Category"`. It is something like `"Tags"`, just it is **unique** per post.

Anyway, I need to append this to the query above:

```
INNER JOIN category_pivote cp
        ON p.id = cp.post_id
INNER JOIN categories c
        ON c.id = cp.category_id AND c.name = "technology"
```

How can I combine those two queries?

Comment: I don't understand the issue, why can't you just add them to the joins in the first query?

Comment: @HoneyBadger Because I don't know how should I behave with `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;`. Actually I don't understand how `GROUP BY` works in my query.

Comment: That's because your group by is wrong, and won't execute in most dbms's. Even newer versions of mysql won't allow it (in default settings).

Comment: if p.id is a primary key the query is valid @HoneyBadger.. p.* is then functional dependend within MySQL

Comment: @HoneyBadger I was literally typing that! lol

Comment: @RaymondNijland It is only valid on MySQL prior to 5.7 (depending on configuration) It is an invalid query according the SQL ANSI specification.

Comment: @JorgeCampos true i've changed mine comment before your comment about the ANSI SQL standard dont know what i was thinking geuss i need some coffee.. Besides i won't recommend using `SELECT p.* ... GROUP p.id`assuming p.id is a primary or unique key and trust on the functional dependend "feature"..Because the MySQL's versions and configuration difference between servers might mess up the functional dependend "feature"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method using `join`s is:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p INNER JOIN
     category_pivote cp
     ON p.id = cp.post_id INNER JOIN
     categories c
     ON c.id = cp.category_id AND c.name = 'technology' INNER JOIN
     tags_pivot tp 
     ON p.id = tp.post_id INNER JOIN
     tags t
     ON t.id = tp.tag_id AND t.name IN ('mysql', 'php')
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.name) = 2;
```

I added the `DISTINCT` just in case multiple categories match (although that seems unlikely).  You could also use:

```
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.name ORDER BY t.name) = 'mysql,php';
```

Comment: Ok thank you, upvote. Just your query won't work in the newer versions of mysql  ?

Comment: @stack . . . The easiest thing to do is to just add all the columns in `posts` to the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2):

To add another pivot relation to your existing pivot query you can add these joins as regular but you need to update `having` clause to get only for distinct tag ids

```
SELECT p.id, p.name
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN tags_pivot tp 
     ON p.id = tp.post_id
INNER JOIN tags t
     ON t.id = tp.tag_id
INNER JOIN category_pivote cp
        ON p.id = cp.post_id
INNER JOIN categories c
        ON c.id = cp.category_id
WHERE t.name IN ('mysql', 'php')
AND c.name = "technology"
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) = 2;
```

Above query will return you those posts who have 'mysql', 'php' tags and category for post is 'technology'

Also include only those columns in select list which are present in group by clause because newer version of mysql will reject these queries.

Answer (score 1):

A CTE should work on MySQL 5.5 and newer:

```
with x as (
  SELECT p.*
  FROM posts p
  INNER JOIN tags_pivot tp 
       ON p.id = tp.post_id
  INNER JOIN tags t
       ON t.id = tp.tag_id AND t.name IN ('mysql', 'php')
  GROUP BY p.id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
)
select * from x
  INNER JOIN category_pivote cp
        ON x.id = cp.post_id
  INNER JOIN categories c
        ON c.id = cp.category_id AND c.name = "technology";
```

Comment: CTE is MySQL 8.0+ not MySQL 5.5+  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html  check there isn't documentation about CTE in lower versions.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Without noticing I tried it in my MySQL 8 server, rather than 5.5.